# About a simple equivalent definition of coninuity

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ a complex valued function with domain an open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C} $. Suppose that $f$ is continuos on $\Omega$.
By the definition of continuos function, i get that $$ \lim_{w \rightarrow z} f(w)=f(z)$$  with $w ,z \in \Omega$.
Is it true that the definition of continuity is equivalent to say that $f(w)-f(z)= \phi(w)$ with the function $\phi(w)$ that goes to zero while $w \rightarrow z$?

Comment: In addition, phi(w) should be defined to be zero at w=z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean to say that $f$ is continuous at $z$ if the function $\phi(x) = |f(z) - f(x)|$ satisfies that $\lim_{x \rightarrow z} \phi(x) = 0$. And yes, this is a correct definition. In fact, this is sometimes how continuity is defined in textbooks.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{w \to z}f(w)=f(z)$

iff

$\lim_{w \to z}(f(w)-f(z)=0$